# Multiple key value not printing

Tags: titan

Here I am setting multiple value for key `city`

```
Vertex v = g.addVertex(null);
TitanVertex v2=(TitanVertex)v;
v2.addProperty("city", "NY");
v2.addProperty("city", "WS");
v2.addProperty("city", "PER");
g.commit();
```

Here i am indexing

```
g.makeKey("city").dataType(String.class).indexed("search", Vertex.class).make();
```

When I do below

```
TitanVertex tv = (TitanVertex)vertex;
Iterator<TitanProperty> iterator = tv.getProperties("city").iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
   TitanProperty next = iterator.next();
   System.out.println(next.getValue());
}
```

It only print `PER` but not `NY` 'WS`. Why?

Comment: For `NY` you wrote `city` instead of `City` as Property name: is it a typo in your code on just here?

Comment: oh sorry its `city` but still result is same i.e. only `PER` is printing

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use `.list()` to create a multi-value key (otherwise the default is a single-value key; see [docs](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview#single-and-multi-value-keys)).

Unfortunately, I'm not sure you can use multi-value keys in your external index:

```
gremlin> g.makeKey("city").list().dataType(String.class).indexed("search", Vertex.class).make();
Only standard index is allowed on list property keys
```

With a standard index, though:

```
gremlin> g.makeKey("city").list().dataType(String.class).indexed("standard", Vertex.class).make();
==>city
gremlin> v = g.addVertex(null)
==>v[4080012]
gremlin> v.addProperty("city","NY")
==>e[2esPj-h7oE-h4][4080012-city->NY]
gremlin> v.addProperty("city","WS")
==>e[2esPl-h7oE-h4][4080012-city->WS]
gremlin> v.addProperty("city","PER")
==>e[2esPn-h7oE-h4][4080012-city->PER]
gremlin> g.commit()
==>null
gremlin> v.map
==>{city=[NY, WS, PER]}
```